# Connection status function gives error and does not working right

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

This is part of my Python software to control Smart TV. I have function "connection_status".

```
import fcntl, socket, struct
import base64
import time, datetime
import netifaces
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Pepin's Samsung Smart TV Remote")
root.geometry("391x595") #391

class Application():
    """Pepin's Samsung Smart TV Remote"""

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def connection(self):

        self.connection_status()


    def connection_status(self): // this is the function that does not work right.

        try:

            connection_status = sock.recv(64)
            print("Status: Connected")
            self.label_connection_status['text'] = 'Status: Connected'

        except socket.timeout:

            connection_status = ""
            print("Status: Disconnected")
            self.label_connection_status['text'] = 'Status: Disconnected'

        self.master.after(1000, self.connection_status, self.master)

    def create_widgets(self):
            btn_connect = Button(self.master, text = "CONNECT TO TV", width=19, height=2, command = lambda: self.connection()) 

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But when i call the function, it outputs me this error:

```
Status: Connected
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1535, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 586, in callit
    func(*args)
TypeError: connection_status() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

And even if TV disconnects, the status stay "Connected"!

Comment: how are you calling `connection_status` ? the error says you are calling the function with an additional argument but the function takes `self`

Comment: @jonrsharpe no, I dont give any args.

Comment: @aschmid00 ye, via self. Added to main post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont have more. I simply have button that call function, and in that function dont work right. And it outputs only this 1 error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, I forgot to add definition, I updated the main post. Also i dont have this comments in code, I just writed it here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, all added to code, also i have night and im little bored so.. ye Im stupid sorry.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok and sorry, but you need first setup a socket connection before calling connection_status

Comment: Doesn't `self.master.after(1000, self.connection_status, self.master)` call self.connection_status with self.master as its argument?

Comment: @multivac probably, it calls connection_status every 1000 to detect state

Comment: Change it to `self.master.after(1000, self.connection_status)`. The 3rd argument is being passed to the function.

Comment: @multivac tahnks! I tryied it before you post, but anyways thanks! But I got only 1 problem left: if I dont stream any data (keys for tv..) the status will change to disconnected and if I send data again it changes to connected...

Comment: The timeout dont work... even if i turn off tv, still its connected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `self.connection_status` with this line of code:

```
self.master.after(1000, self.connection_status, self.master)
```

That will result in the following function call:

```
self.connection_status(self.master)
```

However, `connection_status` doesn't accept any arguments other than `self` which is automatically added by python. That is why you are getting the error `connection_status() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. `self` is the first argument, and `self.master` is the second argument, but the function is designed to accept only `self`.

There is almost never a reason to pass an object attribute to another method of the same object, since that method has immediate access to those attributes. So, the simple solution is to remove the parameter from the `after` call:

```
self.master.after(1000, self.connection_status)
```